# iPhone development - Locate address from user's position

Tags: iphone, core-location

Is it possible to get the street/area where the user currently is by using the CoreLocation framework? So if I get the user's longitude and latitude position, can I get the address (xx street, yy city, z state) from that position?

Thanks.

***Someone had already posted the question before. Just found out [Get street address at lat/long pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair)***

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get street address at lat/long pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would need is a reverse geocoding service, that will translate a lat/lon coordinate set in to an address. I doubt that this, or access to one, is included in CoreLocation.

You could look into a third-party provider such as Google Maps:

http://nicogoeminne.googlepages.com/documentation.html

There are also other work-arounds that might get you close. For example by using Multimap's routing API as described in the following:

http://forums.multimap.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=51

Answer (score 4):

Agreed - you need a reverse geocoding service - this is not included in Core Location. There is a fairly complete list of reverse geocoders here [link text](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/resources-non-google-geocoders)