# Perform reverse geolocation lookup

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I'm pretty new to iPhone SDK and Cocoa development. I'd like to know how to call a web service which will take the lat and long values from my iPhone and feed them to a webservice so I can retrieve the City,State. I already have the phone location stuff squared away. I'm only looking for where I should pass this info to and how I can parse this data back into my app.

Essentially, I only want "City,State" to be visible in a label on one of my views.

The first time I tried this was with geonames.org and it put my returned lat/lng location in the middle of nowhere many many many miles from where I actually was. I tried the same lat/lng values with google maps api and it was in the right place. The only problem I've had is parsing the JSON data back into my app. The returned info seems to have multiple versions of the same info which I can't seem to understand how that works.

So once again. Just looking for a simple HTTP style string I can pass somewhere with my lat/lng values and it returns "City,State". If the example you mention involves parsing data. Please refer to an example I can dissect - I'm a noob.

Oh and one last thing, I know this was made possibly easier with the iPhone 3.0 SDK but I'm currently building this project on 2.2.1 - and for more than enough reason HAVE to do it this way until the rest of the app is ported to 3.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get street address at lat/long pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524077/iphone-development-locate-address-from-users-position) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair)