# Can anyone recommend a free geocoding service?

Tags: geocoding

Whatever service that would allow something as simple as 100 geo transcoding requests (from street address to geocode) would be ideal. I know that google maps allows 15000 daily, but it is written in Javascript. I was wondering if I could get something written in a language that at least allows for database connections.

Comment: I have released an open source server for geocoding, you can find it at geocodeforfree.com or at https://github.com/bwheeler96/Geocode-For-Free

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [non-JavaScript variant](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) of the Google Maps geocoder (check the TOS - you'll need to be doing this to eventually display stuff on a Google map), and you're not going to find any geocoding services that allow a direct database connection.

Comment: I meant a language that would support a DB connection.

Comment: The non-JavaScript variant can be used in any language, as it provides easily readable XML and JSON data formats.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use [OpenStreetMap Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) if its crowd-sourced data with [CC-BY-SA licence](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Licence) suits your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Check out geoservices.tamu.edu We offer `100% up to 2500` records at a time and all you have to do is upload your database and let it geocode away. The database will then be available for you to download complete with a miriad of populated data in addition to very accurate lat/long coordinates.

Census data, parcel data etc are all included in database as well. The only programming involved would be what you would want to do with the data once you've downloaded it.