# Is there any free address validation service?

Tags: geocoding

I am looking for an address validation service which is not only free of charge but also available world-wide (or at least in Europe).

Background: I want to check the customers address in the background of a checkout process in an online shop. Currently this check is done manually by service staff after the the order is placed.

Note: I don't want to bother the user with error messages, the check should only be done in the background to reduce effort and time in the backend.

Every free service I found (Google Maps, Yahoo Places) exludes the right to use their data within any scenario like that. And any commercial I found till now is a bit to expensive in that context.

Thanks for any hint :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone recommend a free geocoding service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283689/can-anyone-recommend-a-free-geocoding-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's asking a lot, even in this age of free open-source community-licensed software.

In the UK at least, you need to licence the Royal Mail's Postcode Address File (PAF) for that sort of detailed check.

However, a quick Google for Merchant services shows up several that include this check as part of their service.

It may be cheaper to assume validity (just sense-check the address during checkout) and pay a premium to insure yourself against fraudulent purchases would be my advice.

Answer (score 1):

As Widor answered, many countries have fees/licenses associated with getting access to their postal data so. I am not aware of any free solutions that will verify postal data.

Also worth noting verifying addresses on Google Maps / Yahoo doesn't necessarily mean that they are a deliverable address for mail/packages.

There are some good commercial solutions that are affordable, consumption based, and do not require the purchase of software. If you decide to go that route, please take a look at StrikeIron (full disclosure, my company), we offer a Web Service with monthly/yearly subscriptions (with a free trial) to do international and North American address verification.

Best,

Justin

Comment: Need to fill out a form to get pricing info. Meh.